# Static Block Text only on certain store

Tags: static-block

My magento has 2 stores, blue and white.

I have a static block which contains links to cms pages for a left menu.

The static block displays on both stores, but I took one of the cms pages pages off the white store.

Am I able to do some kind of an if statment in the static block to only display the link to that one cms page on blue only, since on the white store it just goes to 404?

Thanks!

EDIT:

in 2columns-right.phtml I have

```
<div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
```

and in page.xml

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
    <label>Right Column</label>
</block>
```

Comment: Tell us how you show the static block (code), then probably someone can help.

Comment: try `Mag::app()->getStore()getId();` to determine if you should show it

Comment: can you please provide site url with that page??

Comment: I updated my post with the code I use to show the static block @simon

Comment: It's on my local machine @keyul-shah

Comment: make sure you are assign that static block for all

Comment: I have the static block enabled on both stores, I just want a part of text in that static block to only show on the blue store, and hide it on the white store. @keyul-shah

Comment: I think that is css issue may be text are not fit with that make sure that

Comment: the question is not at all clear

Comment: @programmer-rkt What's not clear about it? I have a static block with a bunch of links... I have 2 stores in magento, one is named blue and the other is named white. The static block with all the links is enabled on both of the stores in magento, BUT I only want one of those links to show on one store, and not the other.......

Comment: @BrandonStewart you still did not show us the code where you add your static block... The right column definition above is Magento standard, but where/how do you add your static block?

Answer (score 2):

<sub><sup>Sorry for my comments - in the end the code is not really needed...</sup></sub>

If you create a static block, there is a StoreView dropdown. You can simply create two static blocks with the same (!) identifier. In one static block, you only select the blue StoreView and enter the links which should be shown in the blue store. In the other static block, you only select the white StoreView and enter the links which should be shown in the white store. Then, the static block of the matching store will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

> As a rough workaround you can use layout handles specific to each
>   store. For example;

**_de and _en my store code**

```
   <STORE_de>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="Promo_de">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_de</block_id></action>
            </block> 
        </reference>
    </STORE_de>
    <STORE_en>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="Promo_en">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>promo_en</block_id></action>
            </block> 
        </reference>
    </STORE_en>
```